# Why does PyTorch require to retain graph?

Tags: python, pytorch

I train my model like this:

```
for i in range(5):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  y = next_input()
  loss = model(y)
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```

and get this error

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
```

Why does it require me to retain the graph? It could just recalculate derivatives if they are freed. To prove it consider the code:

```
for i in range(5):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  model.zero_grad() # drop derivatives
  y = next_input()
  loss = model(y)
  loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
  optimizer.step()
```

In this case the derivatives from the previous iteration are also zeroed, but Torch doesn't care because the flag `retain_graph=True` is set.

Am I right that `model.zero_grad()` cancels the effect of `retain_graph=True` (i.e. drops the retained derivatives)?